# Footer background not showing correctly?

Tags: css, html

I want to achieve this:

[image]

I have achieved this:

[image]

Why is the background of footer not showing correctly. Also why is the margin-bottom of 'home-features' section not working? The page is live at http://goo.gl/OpAB4V

Markup:

```
<section id="home-features">
<article class="home-feature-box">
<img src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_33.png" alt="">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed felis porttitor elementum</p>
</article>
<article class="home-feature-box">
<img src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_33.png" alt="">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed felis porttitor elementum</p>
</article>
<article class="home-feature-box-right">
<img src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_33.png" alt="">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed felis porttitor elementum</p>
</article>
</section>
<footer>
<p>Copyright &copy; 2014, Tellerest. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
/* home features section */
#home-features { margin: 40px auto 0 auto; width: 950px; text-align: center;}
.home-feature-box { width: 256px; float:left; margin-right: 91px;}
.home-feature-box-right { width: 256px; float:right;}
#home-features p { font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 24px; color: #4f4f4f;}

/* footer */
footer { background-color: #fafafa; border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0; text-align: center; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; color: #a3a3a3; padding: 15px 0 30px 0;}
```

Comment: The link you posted has `background-color: #fafafa; border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;` CSS in footer TAG. removing this solves issue.

Comment: No, that's not the issue at all. His issue is that he needs to clear his floats, and also that his main content div has a height-cap of 1000px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must clear your floats.

After the last article, add this div:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Of course, you should simply create a "clear" class instead of having inline styling, but you get the idea.

Upon observation, I see that your `#container` div also has a fixed height of 1000px. Simply remove that as well.

Comment: Create a jsFiddle with your code, because the issue IS indeed that you must clear your floats. We just have to figure out where exactly to do so.

Comment: Wait, I see your issue on your live code. First of all, do what I said about adding the div, but then also see that your #container div has a fixed height of 1000px. Simply get rid of the height cap.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your #container class to following code.

```
#container {
  background-image: url("images/tellerest-homepage-design2_01.png");
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given `height:1000px`  for `#container`

Remove that height and clear the div

```
 <section id="container">
.
.
.
<div class="clear"></div>

</section>
```

CSS for clear

```
.clear {
clear: both
}
```